# Optimizing file reading from HD

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, file-io, ntfs

I have the following loop:

```
for fileName in fileList:
    f = open(fileName)
    txt = open(f).read()
    analyze(txt)
```

The `fileList` is a list of more than 1 million small files. Empirically, I have found that call to `open(fileName)` takes more than 90% of the loop running time. What would you do in order to optimize this loop. This is a "software only" question, *buying a new hardware is not an option*.

Some information about this file collection:

Each file name is a 9-13 digit ID. The files are arranged in subfolders according to the first 4 digits of the ID. The files are stored on an NTFS disk and I rather not change disk format for reasons I won't get into, unless someone here has a strong belief that such a change will make a huge difference.

## Solution

Thank you all for the answers.

My solution was to pass over all the files, parsing them and putting the results in an SQLite database. No the analyses that I perform on the data (select several entries, do the math) take only seconds. Already said, the reading part took about 90% of the time, so parsing the XML files in advance had little effect on the performance, compared to the effect of not having to read the actual files from the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If opening and closing of files is taking most of your time, a good idea will be use a database or data store for your storage rather than a collection of flat files

Answer (score 2):

#### Hardware solution

You should really benefit from using a [solid state drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) (SSD). These are a lot faster than traditional hard disk drives, because they don't have any hardware components that need to spin and move around.

#### Software solution

Are these files under your control, or are they coming from an external system? If you're in control, I'd suggest you use a database to store the information.

If a database is too much of a hassle for you, try to store the information in a single file and read from that. If the isn't fragmented too much, you'll have much better performance compared to having millions of small files.

Comment: SSD's don't work well with a lot of small files on random places.

Comment: Actually, lots of small random reads is where SSDs have the biggest advantage over hard drives. Sure, they're even faster at sequential reads, but it's their random access performance that is their main selling point.

Comment: Yes, the biggest advantage of SSDs is seek latency, not sequential read/writes. Tons of small files is exactly where SSDs excel the most.

Answer (score 0):

To address your final point:

> unless someone here has a strong belief that such a change will make a huge difference

If we're really talking about 1 million small files, merging them into one large file (or a small number of files) will almost certainly make a huge difference. Try it as an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's get this straight: you have sound empirical data that shows that your bottleneck is the filesystem, but you don't want to change your file structure? Look up Amdahl's law. If opening the files takes 90% of the time, then without changing that part of the program, you will not be able to speed things up by more than 10%.

Take a look at the properties dialog box for the directory containing all those files. I'd imagine the "size on disk" value is much larger than the total size of the files, because of the overhead of the filesystem (things like per-file metadata that is probably very redundant, and files being stored with an integer number of 4k blocks).

Since what you have here is essentially a large hash table, you should store it in a file format that is more suited to that kind of usage. Depending on whether you will need to modify these files and whether the data set will fit in RAM, you should look in to using a full-fledged database, a ligheweight embeddable one like sqlite, your language's hash table/dictionary serialization format, a `tar` archive, or a key-value store program that has good persistence support.

Answer (score 0):

Store the files in a single `.zip` archive and read them from that. You are just *reading* these files, right?